# An inequality about metric spaces

Tags: limits, inequality, metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry

I started studying this article about 3 months ago: arxiv.org/abs/1605.05583

In this article, there is a seemingly simple assertion on page 27 that troubled me for several days:

"The statement $(1)$ follows now easily by the combination of $(3.39)$ and $(3.41)$."

In fact, I think there are some mistakes here.

The three conclusions are as follows:
$(1)$. $ (1 - \epsilon )d(x,y)^{\epsilon} \le \frac{|\Phi (x) - \Phi (y)|}{d(x,y)} \le d(x,y)^{-\epsilon} $, 
$(3.39)$. $ |\Phi (x) - \Phi^\alpha (y)| \le \eta^{4+2\alpha -2\alpha\eta} $, 
$(3.41)$. $ (1 - \eta^3 )(1 + \eta^2)^{-\alpha } \le \frac{|\Phi^\alpha (x) - \Phi^\alpha (y)|}{d(x,y)} \le (1 + \eta^3 )(1 + \eta^2)^{\alpha } $, 
where $\Phi = \lim_{\alpha \to \infty }\Phi^\alpha$, $\eta \in (0,1)$, $\eta^{2+2\alpha } < d(x,y) \le \eta^{2\alpha } $. (By the definitions in page 20 and page 25, $r_{x}^{\beta} = t_{\beta } = \eta^{2\beta}$ when $x\in C_{0}$. )

Consider the left side of inequality $(1)$. Apply $(3.39)$ and $(3.41)$ directly, we have:
$$\frac{|\Phi (x) - \Phi (y)|}{d(x,y)} \ge (1 - \eta^3 )(1 + \eta^2)^{-\alpha } - \eta^{2-2\alpha\eta}.$$

When $\alpha$ is large enough, the right side of the inequality becomes negative, so I cannot get $(1)$.

Because this article was accepted by Annals, I think this statement should be right. Is there any special inequality technique to be used here?

Thank you!

Comment: I have no idea what the article is about, but this assertion is on page 27, and it may be important that $\epsilon > 0$ is arbitrary and $\mu = 10^{-6n}\epsilon^2$.

Comment: You are right, this assertion is on page 27. But $\epsilon$ is fixed here, and I think $\mu$ is unimportant here. Thank you!

Comment: I see my mistake. At the bottom of page 25 we have $\eta = 10^{-6n}\epsilon^2$. I have mixed up the spelling of the Greek letters.

Comment: I think this is not the center of the problem, the problem lies in the process of taking the limit to $\infty$.